# Agent Pool - VMSS and a high scaleing issue

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-vm-scale-set

we have a deployed VMSS to run an Agent Pool inside our environment.

In Azure DevOps we have set `Standby = 0` as the Agents are not required the whole time.

When now a single pipeline starts, we see a "Scaling out" from `0 to 4`, I would expect from `0 to 1`

[image]

Overprovisioning on the VMSS is `Not enabled`

Why does it spin up so many instances?

Thanks in advance

Joerg

Answer (score 0):

Try set "Maximum number of virtual machines in the scale set" to "1".

[image]

You could find this setting in Azure DevOps -> Agent pools -> choose your target VMSS agent pool -> Settings

Comment: But that will not help if multiple pipelines has to run in parallel...

Comment: If your single pipeline has only one job, it should be "0" to "1". If your single pipeline has 4 jobs (No dependency, self-hosted parallel jobs >4), it will be "0" to "4", because the 4 jobs run in parallel.

Comment: The pipline has 4 stages with in total 6 jobs. Dependencys are only defined explicit in two stages, which have each two jobs inside. so do I need to define the dependency between the stages explicity too, even if the are processed in right order?

Comment: Yes, your understanding is right. For this single pipeline, you could do a test by defining the dependency between the stages explicitly too. Then check the "Scaling out" number.

Comment: I have done so and it's still doing `0 to  4`

Comment: I have this same issue. I set my maximum number of virtual machines to 100, as our pipeline can get under heavy load. I ran a test which queued up 4 jobs in the agent pool, and it immediately started 35 machines. When I reduced the maximum to 30, it scaled up to 13 machines when 4 jobs were added to the queue.

Answer (score 0):

The additional instances may be caused by the Default scale-in policy, see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machine-scale-sets/virtual-machine-scale-sets-scale-in-policy?WT.mc_id=Portal-Microsoft_Azure_Monitoring#default-scale-in-policy

> By default, Virtual Machine Scale Set applies this policy to determine
> which instance(s) will be scaled in. With the Default policy, VMs are
> selected for scale-in in the following order:
>
> ```
> * Balance virtual machines across availability zones (if the scale set is deployed in zonal configuration)
> * Balance virtual machines across fault domains (best effort)
> * Delete virtual machine with the highest instance ID
> ```
>
> Users do not need to specify a scale-in policy if they just want the
> default ordering to be followed.
>
> Note that balancing across availability zones or fault domains does
> not move instances across availability zones or fault domains. The
> balancing is achieved through deletion of virtual machines from the
> unbalanced availability zones or fault domains until the distribution
> of virtual machines becomes balanced.

Answer (score 0):

The simple answer to your question would be this:

*"Scaling out is done in increments of a certain percentage of the maximum pool size."*

Which you can find in the official Microsoft documentation for VMSS agents here:

[How Azure Pipelines manages the scale set](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/scale-set-agents?view=azure-devops#how-azure-pipelines-manages-the-scale-set)

I just asked a similar question about this, but more in depth, which you can find here: [VMSS agent pools - Scaling percentage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77463059/vmss-agent-pools-scaling-percentage)

The why and how is what I'm looking for. The reasoning behind the why and the algorithm behind the how. One could also ask themselves why you can't opt out of this and have it to scale 1:1 with your actual queue (my guess that it's an an attempt to optimize waiting, cost and requests to the VMSS in contrast to each other, as well as other potential factors), but perhaps the **why** will answer that.